# How do I make Windows 7 count bytes in base 10 rather than base 2?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Windows counts kilobytes etc. as 1024*n bytes. Other OS count those as 1000*n. How do I make Windows 7 count kilobytes as 1000*n bytes?

In case this is confusing (which I suspect it is), Windows tells you that a 100MB file is equal to 104,857,600 bytes (rather than 100,000,000) because it thinks 1 kB = 1024 bytes. While there is confusion among many experts about if this is correct I think that this is ugly, regardless of whether it's correct. I want it to show me 100,000,000 bytes.

This question could apply to all Windows OS versions, but I'm specifically asking for Windows 7 - just to avoid any additional confusion.

Comment: "because it thinks 1 kB = 1024 bytes"  But, one KB _IS_ 1024 bytes, "ugly" or not.

Comment: Windows doesn't have this feature.

Comment: To be 100% accurate:

1000 Bytes equal 1 kilobyte.  
1024 Bytes equal 1 Kibibyte.

This is a standard defined by the International System of Quantities (see this simple Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)

But I don't know whether there is such a feature in Windows, nor do I know how to activate it.

However I can advise you: If you are serious about IT, get comfortable with two potentials. You'll need them very often.

Comment: See, confusion among experts, in this exact comments section.

Comment: Take a look at [UnitPolicy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy)

Comment: Part of me wants to say, "If there's confusion, are they really experts?"  This has been a known "oddity" for as long as there has been a kilobyte.  Ironically some of the confusion is caused by the transition to the "kibi" prefixes.  Some of us stubborn types have been into computing long before the new prefixes gained any traction.  Traditionally, kilobyte _usually_ meant 1024 for programmers, so now when we say kilobyte, people aren't sure if we mean the old context-defined one or the new strictly-defined one.  At least "kibibyte" is clear.

Comment: In many computing contexts the various prefixes do retain their SI meanings. Hard drives have nearly always been marketed using "decimal prefixes", all the way back to the IBM 350 RAMAC's "five million characters". (It is a myth that HD makers switched from binary to decimal prefixes to make the numbers bigger; they never switched.) Tape capacities, CPU and bus clock speeds, and network data rates are other areas where e.g. "mega" means 1,000,000. If anything, RAM sizes and some OS's insistence on using binary prefixes for hard drive and file sizes are the outliers, not the other way around.

Comment: There's a standard for kibi, mebi... which are powers of 2 but almost no one uses it except some Linux distros and modern Mac. [*"Many Linux distributions use the unit, but it is not widely acknowledged within the industry or media"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte). Even when Apple switches to IEC units it causes confusion when people complaining why their drives became bigger. Windows probably won't change this considering its huge user base and I really hope it will never do

Comment: -1 subject is absolutely wrong. If you googled about different bases you'd know that. Total misuse of the term 'base'.  e.g. in Base 16 you have some symbol for the numbers 11-15.  I really don't think you mean to have a special symbol for the number 1023 and for the number 999 and so on. You are using terms you've never read, that you just made up

Comment: if you read the exception part in Ubuntu's Units policy you'll see that `df`, `du` and `ls` still use base-2 units, so a user might ask why their file sizes are different under `ls` and the GUI file manager

Comment: @barlop I agree with you mostly - but I don't know which word would be correct here. I'm aware of what a base is, and that it's not the difference between 2^n prefixes and 10^n prefixes, but I think you know exactly what I'm asking here. Anyway, would you mind telling me which word I should have used?

Comment: @latias1290 normally described as base 2 and base 10, (and that's in the sense of base and exponent, rather than in the sense of number system). So 2^n e.g. getting a result like 1024 would be base 2. Whereas 10^n getting a result like 1000, would be base 10

Comment: @barlop So if I changed "base 1000" to "base 10" and "base 1024" to "base 2" it would be correct?

Comment: @latias1290 I think so. But certainly saying base 1024 is completely wrong (unless you meant having 1024 symbols for 1024 numbers,  or unless you meant 1024^n, which you don't). And you'd never ever see somebody even speak of base 1024 you just made the term up.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make Windows 7 (or any variant of Windows) "count" or measure storage capacity in the way you describe.

This is not "confusion among experts". This is the way it has been. There are sufficient explanations why it is this way already so there is no need to elaborate.

In recent times there have been alternate terms introduced to account for the human desire to make things nice and round, but it is computers we are measuring, not humans, and whether you like it or not computers have been developed in such a way that they are measured using different base- counting systems.